# Check to see if there are active WCF calls on the IIS Server

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, caching, iis

I cache a bunch of data in my WCF Service.  I have a service operation that invalidates that cache and re-fetches it.

However, If I try to re-fetch while I am in the middle of a service call, I could easily make a bad calculation.  (Half of the calculation on old data and half on new data.)

So, I am planning to put a check at the start of each call to see if we are currently trying to refresh the data.  If we are, then I will wait until we are done refreshing.

The problem I have is that I need a way to know that all my "In Progress" calls have finished up.

**Is there a way for a WCF service to know if there are other calls in progress on the server?**

**(Or is there a better way to refresh a cached data for a WCF Service?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **simple locking (using the lock statement)** or another synchronization primitive, e.g. **ReaderWriterLockSlim**, to synchronize the access to your shared resources.

In your case, your shared resource is a cache. You are accessing the cache from multiple threads simultaneously, either reading or updating it. What you actually want to achieve is the following:

1. While you are not updating your cache, any calls may concurrently read from the cache.
2. Whenever you need to update the cache, your updating call should wait until all reading operations have finished.
3. While you are updating the cache, other calls (read or update) must wait until the update is finished.

A [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) can do that for you. Here is some basic implementation that shows how it could be used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

public class SynchronizedCache
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim syncLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public int Get(int key)
    {
        bool lockAcquired = false;
        try
        {
            syncLock.EnterReadLock();
            lockAcquired = true;

            // Get data from cache.
            var data = dictionary[key]; 
            return data;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockAcquired)
                syncLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        bool lockAcquired = false;
        try
        {
            syncLock.EnterWriteLock();
            lockAcquired = true;

            // Do your update work here.
            var random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                this.dictionary[i] = random.Next();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockAcquired)
                syncLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you only need to make sure that all your service instances use the same `SynchronizedCache` instance: Either make it a singleton, or - even better - use Dependency Injection and inject the same cache into all your service instances. Or make the service instance itself a singleton. You probably already have a solution in place for that.

Comment: I need the first.  But CQRS is a architecture overhaul, and I I don't know how to make transactions work outside of a database....  Any suggestions?  I need a WCF solution.

Comment: 1. Where do you get the data from that your cache is made of? 2. How and when is your cache invalidated?

Comment: I get it from a database (it is reference data).  It is invalidated by a Call to a Service Operation that tells me it needs to be refreshed.  (So, my SSIS packages run (every hour or so), then my "RefreshReferenceData" service operation is called.

Comment: Would this be what you want? 1.) `RefreshReferenceData` should wait until all reading operations have finished. 2.) While `RefreshReferenceData` is running, other calls may not read from the cache. 3.) `RefreshReferenceData` must only run once at a time. 4.) While `RefreshReferenceData` is not running, any calls may concurrently read from the cache.

Comment: Yes.  It is #1 that I can't figure out how to do.  That is why I posted the question.  I need a way to know that all the calls to my service have exited.  I can block any new calls till the reference data is updated, but I have no way to know how long I should wait before doing the update.  (My call length can vary based on the complexity of the parameters.)

Comment: Then ReaderWriterLockSlim is your friend. It will do exactly that. It will allow multiple threads to concurrently read. It will allow a single thread to write, as soon as all reading threads have left. Please leave another comment if you need an example.

Comment: This looks good.  I am going to test this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single